# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string error on char variable

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

We just got new computers at work and my SQL-code that I run in Python through cx_Oracle stopped working.

When I run the code it returns the ORA-01861 error saying that the literal does not match format string. I have read that this usually concerns dates, but in this case the error message refers to a char variable named period.

Basically my query says

```
where period = '2015-02'
```

which refers to a year and a month. The datatype in the database for period is char. Does someone recognize this error when dealing with a char variable?

I should say that when I run the same code in SQL Developer it works just fine.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, period is a *string*? `VARCHAR2` datatype column (or any other "`CHAR`")? Are you sure? Because, that Oracle error is related to `DATE` datatype.

Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> desc emp
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 EMPNO                         NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                  VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                    VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                    NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                               DATE           --> HIREDATE is DATE datatype
 SAL                                    NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                   NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                 NUMBER(2)
```

What does my database return for any `hiredate`?

```
SQL> select hiredate from emp where rownum = 1;

HIREDATE
--------
17.12.80
```

Aha; OK, so let's try to select a row using the following date format (note that `'1980-12-17'` is a string, not a date!):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate = '1980-12-17';
select empno, ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate = '1980-12-17'
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Oh? Error just like yours. How about *your* date format?

```
SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate = '1980-12';
select empno, ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate = '1980-12'
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL>
```

Just the same, no difference. Oracle *failed* to implicitly "convert" strings I provided to a valid `DATE` value. So, what to do?

The worst thing is to keep providing strings and hoping that Oracle will guess the format:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate = '17.12.80';

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ---------- --------
      7369 SMITH      17.12.80

SQL>
```

A better option is to take control over it and provide `DATE` value, such as date literal (which always looks like this: `date` keyword, followed by date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format enclosed into single quotes):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate = date '1980-12-17';

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ---------- --------
      7369 SMITH      17.12.80

SQL>
```

This works.

Or, adjust NLS settings for current session (this is kind of a *stupid* format, just to show that it'll work regardless):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/yyyy/dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select empno, ename, hiredate from emp where hiredate = '12/1980/17';

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      12/1980/17

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, I'd suggest you to **a)** check `period` column's datatype, **b)** take control over the process and compare *dates to dates*, not *dates to strings*.

P.S. Oh, yes - why does SQL Developer "work"? Its settings recognized format you provided.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I checked the datatype again for the period variable in the database and it says char(7 char). Could it be related to some settings in cx_Oracle that makes it interpret the SQL-code differently than when I run it in SQL Developer, where it works. The strange thing is that it worked perfectly with cx_Oracle as well before changing computers and reinstalling Anaconda.

Comment: Then it is about NLS settings which is different on your new computer.

Comment: Perfect, then I can boil it down to changing the NLS settings for cx_Oracle to match those of my SQL Developer install?

Comment: I don't know anything about cx_Oracle, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting

```
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'swedish'
```

before my cx_Oracle connection.

I want to thank Littlefoot for helping me to boil this problem down to NLS settings and saved me from missing my deadline.

Comment: This may have fixed the error but it is not a good solution as it relies on setting the NLS settings so that some implicit conversion between data types works; that is not a robust solution as someone will decide that they don't want to have Swedish as the default and then it will all break again. It would be much better to find the actual problem and solve it. My guess is that you have the wrong data type set in a bind parameter in Python but you haven't posted a [MRE] or any Python code so we are just left guessing.